# adb-shell : /sbin/sh: command: not found

Tags: android, shell, adb, cyanogenmod

I've managed to root **Google Nexus 7 (2013 Wi-Fi)** and install **CyanogenMod 10** and **clockworkmod recovery v6.0.1.9** following [this guide](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_maguro) and Everything looks fine.

Then I downloaded and installed **Thinktube image file** to allow ad-hoc networking using [this link](http://www.thinktube.com/android-tech/46-android-wifi-ibss). I am now able to create ad-hoc network in my tablet (not yet tested with other same-model  tablets) and I can see the adhoc network from other iOS phones and adnroid 2.1 only. However, I want to make sure that:

1. do CyanogenMod and Thinktube, together, actually support OLSR rooting
   protocol or not ?
2. if not, then I am following [this guide](http://www.olsr.org/?q=olsr_on_android) to
   download, install and enable OLSR mode. However, when I am in the
   Recovery-mode in my tablet, and when i open the adb-shell from my PC, I can
   list files and browse folders in my tablet normally. But I
   cannot run any other command on the adb-shell. it always gives me this
   error:

   /sbin/sh: *"any-command-rather-than-ls-&-cd"*: not found

   what is this error ? and ..

   why when I try to locate the *wpa-supplicant* in the */data/misc/wifi/* I cannot find it ?

Comment: This question isn't related to programming. This would probably be better at http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for the hint .. honestly I didn't know where to post this question .. it includes too many things and I am really confused .. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recovery has own shell, and many android tools are unavailable in it.

You can't see your files, because you doesn't mount needed partitions. Go to "Mounts & Storage" menu, and select "Mount /data", or type "mount /data" via adb shell. For accessing /system partition you need to do same steps too.

Comment: perfect thanks a lot .. I mounted data folder and now can see the wpa-supplicant

Comment: I am trying to follow this [link](http://www.olsr.org/?q=olsr_on_android), however I cannot do the first command _"make OS=android NDK_BASE=/path/to/your/android-ndk-r8 build_all"_ and it gives me the same error !! .. I am really stuck .. I know I did something wrong but cannot see it

Comment: What are you trying to do? This command need to be runned on PC, not on device.

Comment: I am trying to enable the OLSR routing protocol .. and I am running this command from my adb-shell in my PC after connecting the tablet and be in the Recovery Mode .. am I do it wrong ?

Comment: Yes. You need to install Android NDK to your PC, and do build instructions from your link on it. Then install it to device. Or just unpack [precompiled](http://www.olsr.org/releases/0.5/olsrd-0.5.6-android-samsung-galaxy.tgz) version to your device.